# Is there a unicode character that looks like an ascii one (but isn't equal)?

Tags: unicode, ascii

I'm wanting to write an pre-interview question (for java, but that's not important) that has a different answer if you look at it vs if you copy-paste it and run it *so that we can check if people actually do the problem manually*.

To do this, I'm trying to find a unicode character that will look the same as an ascii character on-screen (so that at some point in my question I can have two methods with the same names but have Integer/int arguments)

I know it's potentially subversive, but I'm hoping it will give an extra metric to validate the other answers.

*Note: I've tried the turkish 'i' - it seems to be ascii - is there a unicode version?*

*Edit/NB:* Looks like my intentions were mis-understood... These questions are intended to be done manually, NOT by a compiler.  If they're copying the text and compiling then they're bypassing the question, and this is intended to trip them up (or more simply give the wrong answer).  The ones that do both will either figure it out, or come to the real interview with confusion that we can help them through.

*Final Note:* :( this doesn't look like it's really possible - most editors (on windows) will attempt to save in cp1252 (somehow my 1 file was saving as UTF-8) in which case I don't think there's any characters that will work without prompting some sort of save error

Comment: Isn't this like having a candidate debug your program written in Whitespace? There has to be a more probing and less irritating way to extract the cognitive ability you seek.

Comment: Someone who manages to outthink your death trap here deserves a job in cryptography or an award for pedanticalness not a job in programming :P

Comment: I don't think the OP's goal is to trick people.  I think it's to determine who thought through the code, and who just went and ran it.  Being 'tricked' is the right answer - it means you didn't cheat.  And who downvotes an honest question like this anyhow?

Comment: Actually, the more I thought about it the worse an idea it seems to give give a candidate a question based on this when you are fuzzy on the distinction between ASCII and ISO-8859-9 yourself.

Comment: This trick only works on the naked unsuspecting eye. But an IDE and a compiler know that appearances can be deceiving. Can't fool em'.

Comment: "Looks like" depends on the font, not Unicode.  Unicode will tell you that there are certain code points, and have sample glyphs, but it doesn't have a standard font.  Cyrillic "C" (the "S" sound) should look similar to the ASCII "C", but whether they're identical depends on the individual font rendering.

Comment: @msw - Thanks for the info. However, I will point out, that even though I did not know about the specific ISO-8859-9 character set, the turkish 'i' is the ASCII 'i' just as it is for ISO-8859-1, and UTF-8.  So you're right, but I wasn't wrong :).  
What I was sort-of looking for was an 'ı' (turkish lower-case dotless 'i') with an extra dot (like the alternative representations of accented characters)

Comment: @Stephen: You may have more luck with _invisible_ (or otherwise nonrendering) unicode characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have actually found something that will work in both UTF-8 and cp1252 encoding (so that it will pass most (all?) text editors): the non breaking space!

Registered at position 160 (00A0, 10100000) in cp1252 and apparently UTF-8 (wikipedia notes it in the range of "Second, third, or fourth byte of a multi-byte sequence"), it provides a character that will "just work"

*Note*: This has been tested to work on windows when copied out of a text file/skype into code editor.  A Wordpress web page did not fare so well (but then it probably changed the character anyhow). Thankfully, our organisation did not pursue the "problems" pre-interview tactic, so I have not tested this definitively on a web page.

Comment: A lone 0xA0 byte is not valid UTF-8, and of course non-breaking space in UTF-8 is not represented as a lone 0xA0 byte.

Comment: That's good to know (+1) - I thought as much.  However, for the purpose of this question, it appears to work well (the code compiles and runs correctly - or wrongly)

Comment: In UTF-8 this would be 0xC2 0xA0, see http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm For a web page you might use `&nbsp;` instead, but in any case it could be translated to a true space by the browser.

Answer (score 4):

You could do something with the same feeling but a slightly less obscure case:

```
System.out.println(100l);
System.out.println(1001);
```

Depending on the font used, these two statements can look very similar indeed. (If that's the case with the font you're using, the first number is 100L.)

Comment: So similar Visual Studio will even warn you not to do this.

Comment: @Matt: Indeed. I've considered logging a feature request for this to be determined by which font you're using. I like the idea of a compiler switch to specify the source font :)

Comment: Hmmm. nice enough, but I think that one will be too hard to hide - it would end up on internet and in editor... however, it won't have the issues with character encoding (I got a compile error on first try when I it at the command line - needed to specify encoding)

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of possibilities - here are just a couple that I found with Windows Character Map. Be aware though that not all fonts will have these characters, so your candidate might not see what you intend.

```
ǃ U+01C3: Latin Letter Retroflex Click
Κ U+039A: Greek Capital Letter Kappa
‚ U+201A: Single Low-9 Quotation Mark
′ U+2032: Prime
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a cyrillic character such as 'a' or 's'.  Take a look: http://jrgraphix.net/research/unicode_blocks.php?block=8

Good idea, by the way, but I wouldn't do a method-overloading answer.  I'd use a switch-case iterating over a string.  That way there's no tip-off that something is wrong, and you can easily pick out the candidates who really know their stuff.

Comment: No I haven't - I don't want a google search to turn up the code. Perhaps I will after this round of interviews...

Answer (score 2):

n-dash or m-dash - look similar to the minus sign.

Answer (score 2):

The Unicode Consortium has a page dedicated to *Confusables*: http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/confusables.jsp

That shows there are plenty of Unicode characters that look similar to an ASCII one:

- Similar to I:   І   ﺍ ﺎ  ℐ ℑ  Ⲓ  ℓ  Ɩ  Ι   ∣ ا Ｉ   1       ׀  ǀ Ӏ ᛁ   I ߊ ｌ  ⵏ    ו       ן Ⅰ  ١   ￨  l ۱ ꓲ     | ⅼ ⏽
- Similar to 5:  5    Ƽ
- Similar to K:    K      Ⲕ ᛕ ꓗ Κ К     Ꮶ  Ｋ
- Similar to :: ः ઃ ܃ ᠃ ׃ ܄ ։ ᠉ ꞉ ᛬ ︰ ː ∶ ˸ : ： ⁚ ꓽ

The exact degree of visual similarity will depend on your font, but in most fonts, at least some of the glyphs will look identical to the ASCII one.